# Should the reference point be mathematically zero or I can pick it zero?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, potential-energy, conventions

$$\int_P \vec E \cdot d\vec l = V(b) - V(a)$$

Now I will assign $V(a) =0$ to get

$$\int_a^x \vec E \cdot d\vec l = V(x)$$

I confused whether $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} V(x)$ should really be  $0$ or I can take $\lim_{x \to a}V(x)$ as $0$ even if $\lim_{x \to a}V(x)$ is not defined or does not equal $0$ ?

As a practical example,

$$V = \int^x_\infty \dfrac{A}{r} dr = A\ln x - \lim_{y \to \infty} A\ln y$$

where $A$ is some constant.

Now can I assign $\lim_{y \to \infty} A\ln y = 0$ ? which does not make any sense.

Comment: @ThePhoton I used it as a parameter of function $V$.

Comment: @UKH Field by an infinite linear  charge distribution.

Comment: @UKH Don't be so literal, of course it is not practical but it is in my book and so it is as practical as a line charge with finite length for me.  Any way it is written in my book that it can be a good approximation for a very long linear charge.

Comment: @UKH $0$ I guess.

Comment: @UKH It doesn't but that certainly is not my question.

Comment: I understand. Think of it in this way. The electric field shows $1/r$ dependence. It vanishes as $r\rightarrow\infty$. Then the potential can have two choices- it can either be a constant at $r\rightarrow\infty$ or zero at $r\rightarrow\infty$. We can choose.

Comment: @UKH You mean if can choose potential is zero or not at infinity ?

Comment: If you choose the potential to be a nonzero value, then it shows no spatial dependence. This means it exists everywhere. A more physical potential will be the one that vanishes at infinity.

Comment: Your doubt is genuine. One thing that you should consider is don't go too much mathematical, constraint yourself to the mathematical part consistent with the physical realm.

Comment: @UKH Thanks for your advice. I will certainly try to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $\vec{E}$ is finite, then

$$\lim_{x\to a} \int_a^x\vec{E}\cdot{\rm d}\vec{l}$$

will be 0.

In the case with $||\vec{E}||\propto \frac{1}{r}$, you should not expect
$\lim_{y\to \infty} \ln y = 0$. In fact this limit is unbounded (infinite).

This field relationship is typically found when the source is an infinite line of charge. And the limit being unbounded is totally consistent with the well-known result that for a line of charge with length L, the potential is given by

$$V(r) = V_0 \ln\left(\frac{d+L}{d}\right)$$

which if taken to the limit of $L\to \infty$ gives an unbounded potential difference between locations on the line and infinity.

Luckily there are no infinite lines of uniform charge density in the real world to make this result represent real physics.

Comment: So in the end, I can't assign any and every term of my wish to be $0$, it has to be mathematically zero in the limit ?

Comment: In realistic situations, you can pick an arbitrary point to have potential zero. In "charge floating in space" problems we usually choose this point to be at infinity. If you have a non-physical charge distribution (like an infinite line of uniform charge density) you may find that some locations have infinite potential. If you unluckily tried picking one of those points as your zero, you would have trouble relating it to the potential at other points.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the potential "has to be mathematically zero" because I'm not even sure that's a meaningful thing to say. I would say you can't choose a point where there is a singularity in the potential.